# Changing Figure caption to Table in Rmarkdown for only a given figure

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, caption

I need to refer to some tables in my `Rmarkdown`, but generating them is difficult and time-consuming. An easier way is to crop the table from the source as an image and place them in my `Rmarkdown`. However, This will create a figure rather than a table in the output. I am wondering if there is any way that I can modify the code to refer to them as **Table 1**, for example, rather than **Figure 1**. Here is the figure:
[image]

and Here is the `Rmarkdown` code:

````
```{r power,echo= FALSE, out.width = '70%',  out.height='70%',fig.align = "center", fig.cap = "\\label{fig:power} Results of application of different types of transformation", fig.pos = "H",dpi=1000, message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
       
knitr::include_graphics("powertranformation.png")

```
````

which generates the following output:
[image]